# How to get price in jquery and plus into total

Tags: jquery, html-lists

**The HTML Code**

```
echo  "<ul id='sub'>";
if($Set == null){ 
echo '<li class="BlankSeat" ></li>';
}
```

**using price according to rows**

```
 elseif($name=='PINK'){
echo '<li class="pink" price="10" title="Row'.$val1.'" name="'.val2.'" 
value="'.$val3.'"></li>';
}
```

**using Different price to this  rows**

```
else{
 echo '<li class="orange" price="15" title="Row'.$val1.'" name="'.$val2.'" 
 value="'.$val3.'"></li>';
 }
echo "</ul>";   
}
echo '</div>';
}
```

**jquery code**

```
var total=0;
var counter = 0;    
var limit=5;
var price=0;
$('li').click(function(e) {
var Lastliclicked = $(this).attr('id');
var price=$(this).attr('price');
if($(this).hasClass('pink')|| $(this).hasClass('yellow') || $(this).hasClass('orange'))
{
if(counter < limit-1)
{
```

**count the clicked aliments in li**

```
counter++;
$(this).addClass('Booked').removeClass(Lastliclicked);
document.getElementById("demoCount").innerHTML=counter;
}
else
{
```

**Remove counts of elements if unclicked li**

```
$(this).addClass(Lastliclicked).removeClass('Booked');
counter --;
document.getElementById("demoCount").innerHTML=counter;
}
```

**getting the total**

```
if(counter < limit)
{
var total= price * counter;
document.getElementById('demoPrice').innerHTML = '$' + total;}});
```

Comment: Question is unclear. can you please elaborate more. Also your current jQuery code will work flawlessly.

Comment: check updated code sir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var total=0;
var counter = 0;    
var limit=5;
var price=0;
  $('li').click(function(e) {
    var Lastliclicked = $(this).attr('id');
    var price=$(this).attr('price');
    if($(this).hasClass('pink')|| $(this).hasClass('yellow') || $(this).hasClass('orange'))
   {
      if(counter < limit-1)
      {
          counter++;
          $(this).addClass('Booked').removeClass(Lastliclicked);
          document.getElementById("demoCount").innerHTML=counter;
      }
      else
      {
         $(this).addClass(Lastliclicked).removeClass('Booked');
         counter --;
         $('#demoCount').val(counter);
      }
      if(counter < limit)
      {
         /*alert(price)*/
         var total= parseFloat(price * counter);
         document.getElementById('demoPrice').innerHTML = '$' + total;
      }
   }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div><ul id='sub'>
<li class="BlankSeat" >BlankSeat</li>
<li class="pink" price="10" title="Row Pink'" name="Pink" 
value="Pink">Pink</li>
<li class="orange" price="15" title="Row orange" name="orange" 
 value="orange">orange</li>
 </ul>  
</div>
<div id="demoCount"></div>
<div id="demoPrice"></div>
```

please try this

```
var total= parseFloat(price * counter);
```

Comment: please try this @krish

Comment: same result nothing change.if i click on first li i get 10 and this is added in total ..but nxt time when i click on li the total was wrong .it is not adding my second li price

Comment: please fetch variable price as said by @Ermanno Palmizio Salieri answer

Comment: Iam getting the right price from li..but when i add this into total that time i facing the problem..first time it adds the right value .but when i click on second li after that iam getting wrong total

Comment: can u provide snippet of your code with html and js

Comment: please see my updated  answer  @krish

Comment: kindly check snippet again sir.. when first time click on pink price is 10 but next time when click on orange price is 30..but in attribute price is 15.. thats the problem iam facing in it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154240/discussion-between-pritamkumar-and-krish).

Answer (score 0):

you should replace "price" in  your li tag with data-price, something like :

```
else{
echo '<li class="orange" data-price="15" title="Row'.$val1.'" 
name="'.$val2.'" 
value="'.$val3.'"></li>';
}
echo "</ul>";   
}
echo '</div>';
```

}

And then in jquery

```
$("li").click(function(){
var price = $(this).data('price');
})
```

or

```
$("li").click(function(){
var price = $(this).attr('data-price');})
```

Comment: check my updated code sir..i need to add total when click on li but iam not  getting right price in var total= price * counter;..it should be not same  every time